# Get all Process ID (PID) in Android OS 7

Tags: android, process, pid, long-running-processes

Before OS 7 i was getting all process ID from this line

```
File[] files = new File("/proc").listFiles();
```

but in OS 7 its not working. I read many things about this but can't find the way to getting all this process ID

please help 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google has significantly restricted access to `/proc` in Android Nougat.
This has already reported:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565 
To get a list of running processes on Android Nougat you will need to use UsageStatsManager or have root access.